# SSIS Pragmatic works task factory upsert error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

We have used "pragmatic works task factory" 2 components i.e. "SalesForce.com Source" and "Upsert Destination".

Local:
All things are working fine on local. TF sales force source and Upsert Destination both are working fine. Upsert Destination is using '.Net Providers\SqlClient Data Provider'.

Server:
After Deployment I am getting below error.

```
"Data Flow Task:Error: There were errors during task validation."   

"Data Flow Task:Error: TF Upsert Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC0010009."     

"Data Flow Task:Error: One or more component failed validation."    

"Data Flow Task:Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC0010009): Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0010009
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSCustomPropertyCollection100.get_Item(Object Index)
   at PW.TaskFactory.UpsertDestinationTask.UpsertDestination.Validate()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostValidate(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)"
```

We are using SQL server 2012 on server.I have searched on internet but not find any solution for this.Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you installed the components on the server?

Comment: Yes I have installed the components on server

Comment: I have installed the trial edition from http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/Task-Factory/CompareEditions

Comment: It might be a legitimate metadata error..... are you running against the same database?

Comment: Yes running against same database. I think I need to contact pragmatic customer support.

Comment: I have deployed it from 2010 SSDT then it is working fine but not from 2012 SSDT